# alignment of div in css

Tags: css, alignment

```
    <span>Text</span>
<div class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-e abc" style=" display:block; border-width:2px; border-style:solid; border-color:red;"></div>
<span>Text</span>
<div class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-e abc" style=" display:block; border-width:2px; border-style:solid; border-color:red;"></div>
<span>Text</span>
<div class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-e abc" style=" display:block; border-width:2px; border-style:solid; border-color:red;"></div>
<span>Text</span>
<div class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-e abc" style=" display:block; border-width:2px; border-style:solid; border-color:red;"></div>
```

Will produce

[image]

How can I format the above code to look like the following

[image]

The property `float: left` is not working as I desired. If I use this for `div`, all the `div`s will come first. Then all the `span` will come second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divs are block level elements so they take up an entire 'line' on the screen. You can set them to `display: inline-block;` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/nLMGT/

Comment: Is there a property called `display: inline-block;` in css ?

Comment: Great. A +1 for it. I am using VS2008 and I get error that 'its is not a valid property'. I could not see markup in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: left;` to make the nodes arrange besides each other.

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: left;` in CSS class

Answer (score 0):

you can use `display:inline` for divs.
use a css class named : "`flt_lt`" and `.flt_lt{float:left;}` don't forget to put a `<br class="cls" />` where `.cls{clear:both;}`
put this `br` after the last div you want in a row.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<span style="float:left;">Text</span><div class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-e abc" style="float:left; width:20px; border-width:2px; border-style:solid; border-color:red;"></div>
<span style="float:left;">Text</span><div class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-e abc" style="float:left; width:20px; border-width:2px; border-style:solid; border-color:red;"></div>
<span style="float:left;">Text</span><div class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-e abc" style="float:left; width:20px; border-width:2px; border-style:solid; border-color:red;"></div>
```